# COVERAGE=true bundle exec rspec --color --profile --format documentation taking too much to process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, github-actions, rspec-rails

I have to run this command `COVERAGE=true bundle exec rspec --color --profile --format documentation`  as final test for my ruby rail application on github actions but only this command is taking more than 15 minutes to complete , is there any way to make it faster ?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to run it faster. Locally, you can use Spring instead of `bundle exec`. In your CI, you can always split your specs in difference tasks and merge result in the next step.

Here is a good one to achieve so on Gitlab-CI: [getting-started-with-simplecov-in-gitlab-ci](https://dev.to/omrisama/getting-started-with-simplecov-in-gitlab-ci-259e)